# Iterating through text nodes to create breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm having trouble with iterating through text nodes to create breaks.

```
        var i;
        var args = ['Once upon a time', 'there were three bears',
                           'and a little girl named goldilocks.'];

        for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            var legendText2 = document.createTextNode(args[i]);
            var legendTextEl2 = document.createElement('p');
            legendTextEl2.setAttribute('class', 'legendPara');
            legendTextEl2.appendChild(legendText2);
            legendTextEl2.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            }
```

For some reason, the code only returns the last item in the array followed by a 'br', rather than returning each item with a 'br' in between'. I'm not sure where I've made a mess in the logic. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have a trailing curly brace that is not required. Please delete the last one. That should've thrown an error.

Comment: @cosmoonot Thanks for catching that! I'm still getting the same issue, however, where the code only returns the last item in the array.

Comment: @KevinJantzer Thanks, I think I just figured it out!

Comment: Use @KevinJantzer's answer. It's perfect.

Comment: Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `legendTextEl2` variable on each loop. I have modified your code. This works for me.

```
    var i;
            var out = document.getElementsByClassName('legendPara');
            var args = ['Once upon a time', 'there were three bears',
                               'and a little girl named goldilocks.'];

            var legendTextEl2;
            var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");   

            for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

                var legendText2 = document.createTextNode(args[i]);
                legendTextEl2 = document.createElement('p');
                legendTextEl2.setAttribute('class', 'legendPara');
                legendTextEl2.appendChild(legendText2);
                legendTextEl2.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                document.body.insertBefore(legendTextEl2, currentDiv);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's cause you keep recreating `legendTextEl2` but so only the last one exists. Try adding this line at the end of the for loop:

```
document.body.appendChild(legendTextEl2)
```

```js
var i;
var out = document.getElementsByClassName('legendPara');
var args = ['Once upon a time', 'there were three bears',
  'and a little girl named goldilocks.'
];

for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
  var legendText2 = document.createTextNode(args[i]);
  var legendTextEl2 = document.createElement('p');
  legendTextEl2.setAttribute('class', 'legendPara');
  legendTextEl2.appendChild(legendText2);
  legendTextEl2.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  document.body.appendChild(legendTextEl2); <-- added missing semi-colon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var i;
        legendTextEl2 = document.createElement('p');
        var args = ['stuff', 'more stuff', 'read this'];
        for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            legendText2 = document.createTextNode(args[i]);
            legendTextEl2.setAttribute('class', 'legendPara');
            legendTextEl2.appendChild(legendText2);
            legendTextEl2.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            }
```

I got this working :)